# Failed to build Bitcoin Core from source, Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-qt-setup

I'm building from source v0.16.0 on Ubuntu 17.10
I cloned the repo, checked out on v0.16.0, ran `./autogen.sh` followed by `./configure CXXFLAGS="--param ggc-min-expand=1 --param ggc-min-heapsize=32768"`

the make command however produces the following error:

```
Makefile:8224: recipe for target 'qt/qt_bitcoin_qt-bitcoin.o' failed
make[2]: *** [qt/qt_bitcoin_qt-bitcoin.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/angelag/src/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:9462: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/angelag/src/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:747: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

from the output of make command the errors started here:

```
...
...
CXX      qt/qt_bitcoin_qt-bitcoin.o
In file included from ./qt/paymentrequestplus.h:10:0,
                 from ./qt/paymentserver.h:35,
                 from qt/bitcoin.cpp:25:
./qt/paymentrequest.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
./qt/paymentrequest.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
./qt/paymentrequest.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
...
...
```

Comment: I take it you have the dependencies specified in `build-unix.md` specific section Linux Distribution Specific Instructions - Ubuntu & Debian - all sections therein?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that protoc was updated since paymentrequest.pb.h was generated (it is not part of the source distribution, protoc generates it). Do `make clean` and then `make`. That should fix this error.